# Add position to a NetworkX graph using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, coordinates, networkx

I have a DiGraph object called G1, a graph network with edges. G1 is composed by a list of nodes and I want to give them coordinates stored in a python dictionary.

This is the list of nodes:
[LIST OF NODES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spsVq.png)

For every node I have built a python dictionary with node's name as keys and a tuple of coordinates as values:

[DICTIONARY WITH COORDINATES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLPpc.png)

I want to add the attribute position (pos) to every node with those coordinates.

At the moment I have tried using this cycle:

[FOR LOOP TO ADD COORDINATES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jog4.png)

But as a result only the last node appears to have coordinates, it seems like the data are being subscribed with this method:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPDKH.png)

The result should be a graph network plotted on a xy space with the right coordinates obtained with the code:
[PLOT THE GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdFIE.png)
I am obtaining the following error:

```
KeyError: (78.44, 88.3)
```

Comment: In the future, it's best to post code and output as formatted text rather than images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's mostly syntax errors here.  Try this:

```
for node, pos in avg.items():
    G1.nodes[node]['pos'] = pos
```

Then, when building your visual, build your list of positions beforehand like this and just use the `pos=pos` convention when calling `nx.draw()`.

```
pos = {node: G.nodes[node]['pos'] for node in G.nodes()}
```

**** **EDIT:** ****

There's a built-in way to do this that is *much* cleaner:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G1, avg, 'pos')
```

Then, when drawing, use:

```
nx.draw(G1, pos=nx.get_nodes_attributes(G1, 'pos'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have tried your solution but when I pass the list of position when calling nx.draw() it returns me a "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" related to the position list.

Comment: Apologies.  I've updated the definition of `pos`.  Does this work?

Comment: @pasq I've added an entirely different solution that uses built-in functions much more cleanly.

Comment: Yes! Now it's woorking. Thank you so much for the effort.